# I want to run both MAMP and native local webserver on mac os x 10.6.4

Tags: php, webserver, local, mamp

I have set up a local webserver using MAMP on ports 8888 for Apache and 8889 for MySQL.
I am using this exclusively for Drupal 6 multisite.
I would also like to have a local webserver using the native mac os x capabilities through ports 80 and 3306. Is it possible to run both MAMP local server and native osx webserver concurrently?
I have tried to install php on my local server by editing the http.conf file but whenever I open a .php file (any php file) using Firefox I get an infinite loop of blank browser windows opening (FF) or in Safari the actual code of the php file is displayed rather than the php processed page.

Have I missed/messed up something?